# Get onmouseover 'event' object when setting function from inside javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I used to have an inline `onmouseover()` defined and used the `event` object:

```
<script>
function foo(e, bar) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  // do something with the coordinates and bar
}
</script>
<div onmouseover="foo(event, 'barValue')"></div>
```

Now I'm generating the `<div>` html via java script, I can't figure out where to get my `event` object from.

```
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.onmouseover = function() { foo(event, dynamicBarValue); };
```

I am not looking for a solution using JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to receive the evt as a first parameter of your listener (check [EventTarget.dispatchEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)). So you could simply do:

```
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.onmouseover = function(evt) { foo(evt, dynamicBarValue); };
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the On-Event handler Properties syntax for adding the event . However, you are trying to **overwrite** the event (Property) in JS code by using Syntax
`d.onmouseover = function() ...`.

You have already specified the event in HTML attribute
   `<div onmouseover="foo(event, 'barValue')"></div>` and this code binds the function `foo` with the `mouseover` event. When you try to add the `d.onmouseover` event again in the JS file it will overrwrite the property and create a new handler for your event.

So, You only need to define the attribute in **either** the HTML code or JS Code.

Moreover, the first argument is the event information.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers),

> When the event handler is specified as an HTML attribute, the
>   specified code is wrapped into a function with the following
>   parameters:
>
> event - for all event handlers, except onerror.
>   event, source, lineno,
>   colno, and error for the onerror event handler. Note that the event
>   parameter actually contains the error message as string.

So, you can achieve the desired effect be defining only one event handler.

```js
function foo(e, bar) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  // do something with the coordinates and bar
  console.log(x,y,bar)
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="foo(event, 'barValue')">Test</div>
```